# HttpClient кэширование данных

Tags: c#, .net

Есть некоторый вебсайт, на котором движок иногда отдает статично страницы из кэша, или просит браузер загрузить их из кэша.
Как можно в буквальном смысле попросить `HttpClient` кэшировать некоторые страницы, и загружать их оттуда, если статус запроса будет 304?

Загружать эти страницы можно и так, игнорируя статус запроса, но это дополнительные расходы времени.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно указать [HttpRequestCachePolicy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.cache.httprequestcachepolicy(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var client = new HttpClient(new WebRequestHandler() {
    CachePolicy =
        new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.CacheIfAvailable)
});
```

Comment: Приношу извинения нашел :) Спасибо.